# Flutter error: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter

You could help me, I'm trying to compile and I get these types of errors.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Problems reading data from Binary store in C:\Users\chimu\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle5211369403093965211.bin offset 267614 exists? true

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: I have same exception , did you got the solution